# RTAB-Map: Merge local grid maps of multi-session mapping

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a large facility I want to map in stages. I've already created a decent map of a large portion of the facility but need to add additional rooms/corridors. I am able to continue mapping by starting on the existing map in localization mode, going to where I want to extend the map, setting rtabmap to mapping mode, and then going into the unknown (as recommended for multi-session mapping). This works but after a little while the occupancy grid map published on `/rtabmap/grid_map` is replaced by a new map that only shows the newly explored area. I understand from [reading in the rtabmap forum](http://official-rtab-map-forum.67519.x6.nabble.com/2D-occupancy-grid-map-does-not-show-when-using-existing-map-to-navigate-tp4719p4852.html) that this is expected, and that the old map may reappear on that topic when the robot is back in that old area and a loop closure is detected. But I still need the complete map for navigation.

Is there a way to ask rtabmap to publish the global, merged 2D map during localization mode? Alternatively, is there a way to export the merged 2D map? I figured out how to export each individual map using rtabmap-databaseViewer (select the right node in the graph view (this step wasn't obvious) > Regenerate optimized 2D map > Export optimized 2D map). So that's a starts, but these maps come without a yaml file containing the origin, so it's not clear how to align them for manual merging.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364067/rtab-map:-merge-local-grid-maps-of-multi-session-mapping/) by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 553 on 2020-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While Miura's answer wasn't a solution per-se it pointed me in the right direction (thanks!).

I just found out that if you make this call:

```
rosservice call /rtabmap/publish_map true false false
```

rtabmap will successively publish *all* local maps on the above topic (including headers with origin), hence giving me a chance to capture them, merge them, and republish in merged form using `map_server` or similar. This is still not the ideal solution but to anyone facing the same issue it gets one unblocked.

---

Originally posted by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) with karma: 553 on 2020-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1